# Magento 2.3: main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file issue

Tags: magento2.3, theme, custom-theme, static-content-deploy, magento2.3.5-p1

I am getting below error when I ran `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f` cmd.

```
frontend/Alothemes/digitalstore3/en_US  2494/2645           ==========================>- 94%    5 secs
Compilation from source /var/www/mag2/app/design/frontend/Alothemes/digitalstore1/web/images/flags/german.jpg failed
Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File\NotFoundException: Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/Alothemes/digitalstore3/en_US/images/flags/german.jpg' in /var/www/mag2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/File.php:160
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/mag2/vendor/magento/framework/App/View/Asset/Publisher.php(74): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File->getSourceFile()
#1 /var/www/mag2/vendor/magento/framework/App/View/Asset/Publisher.php(62): Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\Publisher->publishAsset(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File))
#2 /var/www/mag2/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployStaticFile.php(89): Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\Publisher->publish(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File))
#3 /var/www/mag2/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployPackage.php(189): Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployStaticFile->deployFile('images/flags/ge...', Array)
#4 /var/www/mag2/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployPackage.php(133): Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployPackage->processFile(Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\PackageFile), Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\Package))
#5 /var/www/mag2/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployPackage.php(102): Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployPackage->deployEmulated(Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\Package), Array, false)
#6 [internal function]: Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployPackage->Magento\Deploy\Service\{closure}()
#7 /var/www/mag2/vendor/magento/framework/App/State.php(187): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#8 /var/www/mag2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/State/Interceptor.php(89): Magento\Framework\App\State->emulateAreaCode('frontend', Object(Closure), Array)
```

I am using a third party theme for my store which is https://themeforest.net/item/digitalstore-responsive-magento-1-2-theme/19685939.

I have no idea, How can I resolve this error.[image]

**Magento ver.** : 2.3.5-p1

Any help?

Comment: did you resolve this problem? I have same issue now and I think the problem come from theme

Comment: @huykon225 : Please check my answer. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have resolved my issue to set value 0 in '**theme**' table in db for **type** column.[image]

Comment: Theme is already type value 0 in my case this does not fix it.

Comment: same here. error is no fixed

Answer (score 5):

Just in case someone else runs in to this still:
For us, the parent_id:s of our custom themes were all kinds of messed up, showing up all as parent_id=1;
Fixing the parent_id's from "theme"-table fixed the issue.

f.ex.

```
+----------+-----------+-------------------------+
| theme_id | parent_id | theme_path              |
+----------+-----------+-------------------------+
|        1 |      NULL | Magento/blank           |
|        2 |      NULL | Magento/backend         |
|        3 |         1 | Magento/luma            |
|        4 |         1 | 3rdpartyVendor/base     |
|        5 |         1 | 3rdpartyVendor/child    |
|        6 |         1 | Vendor/frontendtheme    |
|        7 |         2 | Vendor/admintheme       |
+----------+-----------+-------------------------+
```

Switching to correct parents fixed the issue:

```
+----------+-----------+-------------------------+
| theme_id | parent_id | theme_path              |
+----------+-----------+-------------------------+
|        1 |      NULL | Magento/blank           |
|        2 |      NULL | Magento/backend         |
|        3 |         1 | Magento/luma            |
|        4 |         1 | 3rdpartyVendor/base     |
|        5 |         4 | 3rdpartyVendor/child    |
|        6 |         5 | Vendor/frontendtheme    |
|        7 |         2 | Vendor/admintheme       |
+----------+-----------+-------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Run these commands in the order shown and the issue should be solved

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
rm -rf pub/static/frontend/
rm -rf pub/static/adminhtml/
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

the issue is a cache issue, nothing more

Answer (score 1):

> **You need to update the type from the theme table, which may be changed. Please run below SQL**

```
update theme set type=0;
```

[image]

> **Also Please check your selected theme on Admin**

[image]

> **After that, you need to run the below magento command.**

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento s:s:d -f 
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

**Note: If it's still not working then please remove your custom theme entry from the theme table and run the above magento command again. And also select the theme from the admin again.**

Answer (score 0):

You miss this german.jpg file. If you add this file in your ftp, in the correct directory, it will be solved.

Comment: i have the file but still error.

Comment: Same theme? Same Magento version and same error?